# Adding values to Android Resources (eg. string.xml) dynamically?

Tags: android

Is it possible to add dynamically (on run-time) values to android resources file? For example to add new string to string.xml or to add new item to existing string array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not possible to add values dynamically to any part of your resources.

All resources are compiled into a read-only binary file when you generate your apk, and you cannot add extra data to it. You will have to use the internal or external storage for such data.