# How to store the string dynamically in resource file in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I have a string in a `RecyclerView` in  `MainActivity` class. I want to change the language of the content. So for this I have to save the string.

How to store the string in the MainActivity class to resource string file"

Comment: You can't edit resource files at run time. You have to prepare all your localized strings in advance. Refer to the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Comment: Use SharedPreferences for dynamic content

Comment: another tricky tips ! write your json response in to one file and store it in to sd card specific folder,and use it where ever you want .BUT for that you have to clear in advance which string are you going to replace run time from reading that json file.

Comment: It is not possible, see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147971/adding-values-to-android-resources-eg-string-xml-dynamically

Answer (score 2):

You can't change string resource files during runtime.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html):

> String: XML resource that provides a single string. A string resource
>   provides text strings for your application with optional text styling
>   and formatting.

There is no editing option, or any reference of the kind in the documents

string.xml file is made to be accessed for referencing (by name) previously set values.

You could use `SharedPreferences` and still be able to achieve what you are trying to do.
Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) guide.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I have not implemented this library but you can try this. There are two library available on GitHub which provides way to dynamically change the string file and localization on the fly. You can check these library named [Restring](https://github.com/hamidness/restring) and [Philology](https://github.com/JcMinarro/Philology).

Answer (score 0):

As well as I know we cannot change a string in a resources file but yes you can add your data at runtime dynamically in themiddle of that String with the help of (**%1$s** and **%2$d**).

They are called format specifiers. In the xml string they are in the form of

```
%[parameter_index$][format_type]
```

`s` string

`d` decimal integer

`f` floating point number

**Example** :

We will create the following formatted string where the gray parts are inserted programmatically.

This is a `Article and It's Written by Me` and I want to `publish` this article.

**string.xml**

```
<string name="xml_string">This is a %1$s I want to %2$s this article.</string>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
val myString = "Article and It's Written by me"

val secondString = "publish"

val formatted = getString(R.string.this_is_a, myString , secondString)

textViewDynamic.text = formatted
```

It work's perfectly.